# Can I change dynamically the learning rate of a Neural Network in Keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to implement a DQN agent, so a Deep Reinforcement Learning solution.

I should decrease the learning rate after some iterations, without changing the model weights or anything else. In RL problems, the ''fit'' is done after a certain number of new events are collected, and each ''fit'' only has 1 single epoch, so the decaying rates that

at the moment, the only solution I found is doing the following:

```
if(time%1000==0):
    learning_rate=learning_rate*0.75
    mainQN_temp=QNetwork(hidden_size=hidden_size, learning_rate=learning_rate)
    mainQN_temp.model.load_weights("./save/dqn-angle3-"+str(t)+".h5")
    mainQN=mainQN_temp



class QNetwork:
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.01, state_size=4,
                 action_size=5, hidden_size=32):

        # some layers in here

    self.optimizer = Adam(lr=learning_rate)
    self.model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=self.optimizer)
```

which is the most inefficient thing possible. I tried referencing things like mainQN.optimizer.lr with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`K.set_value(model.optimizer.lr, new_lr)` will do. (`K` as in `import keras.backend as K`)

If instead you'd like to reduce `lr` after an arbitrary number of batches fit (i.e. train iterations), you can define a custom callback:

```py
class ReduceLR(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=[]):
        if K.eval(self.model.optimizer.iterations) >= 50:
            K.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, 1e-4)
reduce_lr = ReduceLR()
model.fit(x, y, callbacks=[reduce_lr])
```

Comment: I tried the first solution but I'm getting "AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute 'set_value'", so I tought it was something deprecated...I'll take a look in the callbacks tho, thanks

Comment: @user1834153 `import keras.backend as K` is what you're likely missing (or, if you're using `from tensorflow.keras import ...`, do `import tensorflow.keras.backend as K`)